# Best Practise Create new Object or returning same object

Tags: java, oop, hazelcast

I want to make a Factory that will return an object, this object can be used to interact with the cache systems.

What way is better ? returning a new object each time or just using same object each time.

```
Factory getInstance(Type type){
  switch(type){
    case 1 : return A();
    case 2 : return B();

  }
}
```

or returning same object

```
class Factory {    
  private static A a = new A();;
  private static B b = new B();


Factory getInstance(Type type){
      switch(type){
        case 1 : a;
        case 2 : b;
      }
    }
}
```

The retuning objects of A or B have non static methods that will be accessing Hazelcast server using a single static instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that both A and B do not carry state and are truly thread-save, it can be a nice optimization to reuse the same instance. Following a good example of a Factory pattern is your best bet:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

A common implementation would be to instead create a singleton factory. You see examples of this easily if you search for it. Here is one decent one:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0460__Design-Pattern/SingletonFactory.htm

Answer (score 0):

The general principle is [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

So,

1. Don't reuse the same objects unless it's really needed (e.g. your performance is **really** slow and you've done this decision on a base of profiling results). Doing exist objects reusable you need to manage theirs instances by yourself (using object pools etc.).
2. Try to create you objects immutable unless you have significant reasons. Doing objects mutable you add additional complexity to your code. Thus, you increase probability of adding errors.

**Conclusion:** i'd rather use your first solution without Factory variables. At least as initial Factory implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a DI library. There is a ton a library for doing such things, Spring being the most known. They can generate factory and manage beans for you.

It's probably overpowered for such a need, but I would be surprised you haven't the need on all your application.